# Any option to display multiple HTML pages in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and trying to create a single HTML file of codes with multiple HTML pages. I even know that in jQuery mobile it is possible to link other HTML pages in a single file. so is there any option achieve the multiple html page in single html file in jQuery and not in jQuery mobile. any suggestions. thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="coo drinks">
    <ahref="hot.html">hot</a>
    Coke, Fan ta, Miranda Etc.
</div>
<div id="hotdrinks">
    coffee, tea etc
</div>
```

So in the above code, I want to display the first `div` i.e coo drinks when the page loads and after that when I click the hot link it has to open the `div` whose `id` is "hot". But these things must be in a single HTML file.

Comment: Do you want to use the iframe element?

Comment: i think you mean a single HTML page, right? If ya, load content using ajax

Comment: @roasted: any examples to do with ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"things must be in a single HTML file",
so just hide the div show the content on clicking the link

```
<div id="coo drinks">
   <a class="hotdrink" href="hot.html">hot</a>
   Coke, Fan ta, Miranda Etc.
</div>
<div id="hotdrinks" style="display:none">
    coffee, tea etc
</div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".hotdrink").click(function(event){

        $("#hotdrinks").show();
        event.preventDefault();
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: Shinov T : thanks for the response. but initially my hotdrinks should be hidden , whenever i click on the hotlink at that time it must show();, any suggestions on this.

Comment: You might have missed the change he made to your html. It currently works like you specified.

Comment: I have achieved it like this:  $(function() {
     $("#login").hide();
        $("#loginp").click(function(event){

        $("#login").show();
   $(".container").hide();      
        event.preventDefault();
        });   . but i am unable to click the back button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the load function of jQuery

```
$("#div").load("page.html");
```